# Ros Gazebo development

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to modify the core Gazebo that comes with ROS, specifically Simulator.cc (under the server folder),  it seems that a tarred version of the of gazebo is downloaded from the repository and then extracted and built inside the folder build. However if I edit anything in there, it doesn't seem to have an effect on rosmake gazebo.

If anyone has any tips or has some experience, help would be welcome.
Regards,
Zak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12209/ros-gazebo-development/) by [jks007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1500/jks007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Gazebo that ROS uses is the standard third-party library with a ROS wrapper around it. When you re-make Gazebo, you're pulling down the original source version from the Gazebo site.

In order to modify gazebo itself, you must create a patch for your changes (as a diff against the downloaded version), and add that to the patches/ subdirectory.

Additionally, you can find and replace the original address in all files with the new address on your local machine, then eliminate all autogenerated files with `make clean` or the like. You might also need to remove some conflicting lib files. After that, you should be able to make it fine.

I believe that the default makefile that CMakeLists.txt invokes is Makefile.gazebo.tarball, so that's where I would change the address first if you're going with this route. Just be aware that doing this means that any updates to Gazebo will overwrite your changes. As such, the patch method is safer.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0